# Google sheets copy/paste cell with image inside issue

Tags: image, google-sheets

I have two files - sheets in Google. I want to copy/paste a cell containing picture from the first file into a blank cell in the second file.
But copy/paste doesn't work - the destination cell remains blank.
Any help with that? (I'm using Chrome browser if it matters)

Comment: Since this is not a programing question, but a feature of Google Sheets. You can also contact the Google community directly too [here](https://support.google.com/docs/community)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky.
Please follow these steps

1. <kbd>Right click</kbd> on the image and choose `Put image over cells`

[image]

2.<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd> on the extracted image and choose `Copy image`

[image]

3. `Paste` on your other document.